# Regex backslash issue in Redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I can usually get by with Regex but this one's doing my head in and I will gratefully accept anyone's help.

```
select regexp_replace(upper('Abc\Zyxcz\'),'[^A-Z]+', '');
```

This returns `ABCZYXCZ\` although I'd expect it to remove all the backslashes.

Anything I am missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replacement will only perform one replacement. Add the [g]lobal flag as an extra argument:

```
select regexp_replace(upper('Abc\Zyxcz\'),'[^A-Z]+', '', 'g');
```

Comment: Thank you @trincot - that did resolve it. What a handy thing to know! Thank you.